# Why does AppHostSvc ocassionally get stuck using up 100% CPU?

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, applicationhost

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 server running IIS 7.5 and serving web applications.

I've noticed that a `svchost.exe` process is consuming a lot of CPU (an entire cpu core was at 100%). That specific process was hosting the [IIS Application Host Helper Service (AppHostSvc)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd364269%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). Once the problem starts, it doesn't matter what the server is doing (it could be completely idle otherwise and the service will stake eat up CPU).

If I kill the process the problem goes away - after the service is restarted automatically by IIS it uses a minimal amount of CPU.

The AppHostSvc service is responsible for [IIS Host History Configuration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd364276%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and automatically backs up the configuration (I believe every two minutes by default), I thought maybe the problem starts after an IIS configuration change. I tried to change some configuration settings and it had no effect (even after several minutes of waiting).

Eventually I found what triggers it, but it seems like a bug. See my own answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the trigger was "bad" permissions on the history directory used by AppHostSvc (by default, it's `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\History`)

After making sure the permissions match the [default settings](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981949), I ran [`icacls /T /reset`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525.aspx) on that directory (and on a few others, including `inetsrv\config`) and the problem disappeared - AppHostSvc stopped going crazy with CPU.

---

**More details**

I took a dump of the `svchost.exe` process when AppHostSvc was stuck in the bad state. One of the threads had the following call stack:

```
ntdll.dll!NtClose()
KERNELBASE.dll!FindClose()
apphostsvc.dll!CONFIG_HISTORY_ENTITY::ScanHistoryDirectory(void)
apphostsvc.dll!CONFIG_HISTORY_ENTITY::TrimHistory(void)
apphostsvc.dll!CONFIG_HISTORY_ENTITY::SnapshotConfig(void)
apphostsvc.dll!CONFIG_HISTORY::SnapshotConfigFilesWorkItem(void)
apphostsvc.dll!CONFIG_HISTORY::ExecuteWorkItem(class MULTI_WORK_ITEM *)
apphostsvc.dll!MultiWorkQueueWorkCallback(struct _TP_CALLBACK_INSTANCE *,void *)
ntdll.dll!TppSimplepExecuteCallback()
ntdll.dll!TppWorkerThread()
kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()
```

The function name `ScanHistoryDirectory` suggests it's trying to scan the history directory (duh). I suspected that some permissions were fiddled with in that directory, so I tried to reset them back to default.